# Please explain this php math error to me

Tags: php, math

I'm learning PHP and playing around and I cant figure out why this outputs 150 and not 250

```
$num1 = 10;
$num2 = 15;
($num1 + $num2) * $num1 = $num3;

echo $num3;
```

I understand that my syntax was wrong and that I should put

```
$num3 = ($num1 + $num2) * $num1;
```

But I dont know what PHP's logic is here in getting 150

Thanks

Comment: Is that where you first declare $num3, or is it initialized somewhere above?

Comment: you claim the first chunk of code outputs 150? I don't think so.

Comment: It is outputting 150 - yes it is where $num3 is first declared

Comment: http://3v4l.org/XUYfe

Comment: Did you forget to post the code where you are assigning 150 to $num3?

Comment: No I think I might have had a blonde moment though. Here is my exact block of code and my system did not report that the last line was wrong and so I read only the last value. APologies. http://3v4l.org/fifPe

Answer (score 0):

Blonde moment - I will enact my resignation from chief coder at the nuclear power plant with immediate effect